# Trying to match complicated string using regex in vbscript

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm trying to match "strid" I've tried

```
.Pattern    = "^[\B]{1,}\[0-9]\s\-\s[P][0-9]\s*"
```

pattern but not working.

```
strid = "KB299817 - X3 any string i want"
  Set re = New RegExp
  With re
      .Pattern    = "^[\B]{1,}\[0-9]\s\-\s[X][0-9]\s*"
      .IgnoreCase = False
      .Global     = False
  End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strid = item1.Subject
Set re = New RegExp
With re
    .Pattern    = "^B[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\s\-\s[P][0-9]\s*"
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Global     = False
End With
```

i got this thanks :)

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say that the letter K is optional in your Regex? If so, you may try this one:

```
^K?B\d+\s*?-\s*?X\d (.*)$
```

Otherwise, use this one:

```
^KB\d+\s*?-\s*?X\d (.*)$
```

For the two above regexes, \s*? is just a way to specify that you may have more that one space but in a non greed way, considering the performance of the regex. If you are always sure that only one space will be present, you may just specify it as in:

```
^KB\d+ - X\d (.*)$
```

If VB does not support modern syntax like \d or \s, you may want to use like this

```
^KB[0-9]+ - X[0-9] (.*)$
```

Notice that on all my regular expressions, the last string that you want to catch is inside a group (). Therefore, it will be easy to refer to that part if VB library support it.